# \pgfmathparse returns a phantom .0.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, random

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{random(-5,5)}
\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

Works, but I have a `.0.0` that not supposed to be here.

Comment: I think the problem comes because the lower limit is negative. You may want to have a check on the function `\pgfmathrandominteger`.

Comment: Sorry, but the hint does not actually solve the problem. And I can only guess where the problem is, so I can't write an answer based on this.

Comment: I don't understand, using `pgfmathrandominteger` I have no more unwanted characters and the macro gives good results ? I agree with you the documentation speaks of positive values for `random`, then one can not considere there is a bug in `random` ...

Comment: You're right. Though, to me an answer should explain why with negative values it appears the unnecessary 0.0! The other method works, but it's a workaround.

Comment: The question you want to answer is : why when I use the `random` command in a wrong way, it gives me something bad ? ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the PGF manual, section 90.2.6, page 942 (version 3.0.0)

> `random(x,y)`
>   `\pgfmathrandom{x,y}`
>   This function takes zero, one or two arguments. If there are zero arguments, a uniform random number between 0 and 1 is generated. If there is one argument *x*, a random integer between 1 and *x* is generated. Finally, if there are two arguments, a random integer between *x* and *y* is generated. If there are no arguments, the PGF command should be called as follows: `\pgfmathrandom{}`.

What the manual doesn't say is that the arguments should be non negative. Indeed the simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{random(-1,10)}

\end{document}
```

that should produce no text, creates the following output

[image]

If a random number between –1 and 10 is needed, just use

```
\pgfmathparse{random(1,12)-2}
```

This is to be considered a bug in the documentation.

Comment: It also could produce a random number between -1 and 10. It is sometimes usefull.

Comment: @Tarass Just shift the result: `\pgfmathparse{random(1,12)-2}`

Comment: Ok but why not directly in the function itself?

Comment: @Tarass I guess it depends on the implementation; probably the input is put between `0` and `.0` to shave off the decimal part, but in this case a minus sign will break the macros. This could be a feature request: first `random` normalizes the input to be positive and then subtracts the correct value from the result.

Comment: I don't think this "a bug in the documentation". It is just a bug. The function `random` with two arguments calls `\pgfmathrandominteger`. So either `\pgfmathrandominteger` should check both its arguments are integers or the `random` function should check its arguments before calling `\pgfmathrandominteger`. No prizes for guessing whose fault that is ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found something about this:

Firstly, pgf treats any calculation result as floating point number:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1 + 1};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{-1};
\pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{1};
\draw (\px, \py) circle(2) node[anchor=north west]{\a,\b,\c};
```

So, this will produce `2.0, -1.0, 1`, respectively (`-1` is treated as calculating the negative of `1`).

Then, passing floating point to `random` will result in `.0` because `random` only takes the integer part.

Thus, we just use `random(int(-10), int(10))`, then the `.0` disappears.

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/2b58c0515b431c1061c5044c394ce6d644502180