# How to Generate Random Negative Integer?

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

I am trying to create a worksheet constituted of random numbers so that kids can practice integer operations. E.g.

3+-9=?

2x(-5)=?

18/-3=?

Etc.

How do I do this?

Here is what I've tried so far.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathparse{random(-10,10)}
\pgfmathresult

\end{document}
```

Two problems.

1. Why is there an extra 0.0. before the integer?
2. Why is that random number 7 when my bounds are -10 and 10? Picking 7 repeatedly seems pretty non-random.

Some of this was mentioned in [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197326/pgfmathparse-returns-a-phantom-0-0/220526#220526) but that thread is now a couple of years old.

Got ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `3+-9` is really confusing for kids (and adults also). What does it mean?  is it `3+(-9)`?  Then why not write it as `3-9`?

Comment: @Nasser Because in order to learn that if you add a negative number to a positive number it's the same as subtraction you need to be able to show examples of that.

Comment: `\pgfmathparse{rand*20-10}`? I don't know if this works as you want.

Comment: `\pgfmathparse{rand*20-10}` gave me -19.76776, not an integer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To work around the bug of the `random` function, you may defined a new `randomfixed` function:

```
\tikzset{declare function={randomfixed(\a,\b) = int(random(0,int(\b-\a))+\a);}}
```

Now, you may generate a random integer between two boundaries with parentheses for negative integer:

```
\newcommand\randomint[2]{\bgroup%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{randomfixed(#1,#2)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\final{(\myval < 0)?"(\myval)":\myval}%
  \final\egroup%
}
```

You may generate random operators:

```
\def\ops{{"+","-","\times","/"}}
\newcommand\randomop{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\ops[int(rnd*4)]}\op\egroup}
```

To change the seed of the pseudo-random generator each second, you may use the `\pdfuniformdeviate` macro:

```
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}
```

All the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% fix bug with random(a,b)
\tikzset{declare function={randomfixed(\a,\b) = int(random(0,int(\b-\a))+\a);}}

% get random integer
\newcommand\randomint[2]{\bgroup%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myval{randomfixed(#1,#2)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\final{(\myval < 0)?"(\myval)":\myval}%
  \final\egroup%
}

% get random operator
\def\ops{{"+","-","\times","/"}}
\newcommand\randomop{\bgroup\pgfmathsetmacro\op{\ops[int(rnd*4)]}\op\egroup}

% choose random seed
\pgfmathsetseed{\pdfuniformdeviate 10000000}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,...,10}{
   $\randomint{-10}{10} \randomop{} \randomint{-10}{10} = $\par
}
\end{document}
```

And a result:

[image]

Comment: Above and beyond the question! That's why we all love this site.

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing! Thank you! I only knew I wish enough about TikZ and coding to understand this in just one read. :) I'll keep reading tryis to try to make sense of it. I'll be back posting questions soon. :)

Comment: On closer reading, I actually think that the next step for me is to read the basic documentation on `\pgfmath` stuff. I need to learn the basic ideas and vocabulary. Is that all in the TikZ & PGF Manual? I found "90.2.6 Pseudo-Random Functions" and "90.3 Pseudo-Random Numbers". Is this where I should start reading? Or is there a less techie/more user-friendly way to

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything You may read the part VIII "Mathematical and Object-Oriented Engines" (chapters from 88 to 92) and, may be, "56 Math Library"...

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{
\pgfmathparse{int(rand * 11)}
\pgfmathresult, }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

- The fact that you repeatedly got the same results is due to a missing seed. As you are dealing with a pseudo random number generator, you will get the same sequence otherwise.
- A quick way to generate random integers between -10 and 10, is to generate ones between 0 and 20 and shift them by -10.

---

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed} 

\foreach \n in {1,...,100}{

    \pgfmathparse{random(0,20)-10}
    \pgfmathresult

}

\end{document}
```