# Random Negatives Integers in Basic Factoring

Tags: conditionals, random-numbers

I am trying to create a basic factoring worksheet with random numbers. So far, it's pretty easy if all integers are positive.

That is, it's easy to create x^2+10x+24=(x+6)(x+4) with random numbers.

But I also need some negative integers. I'm not even sure where to start in dealing with the following:

1. The negative random number bug.
2. Removing addition symbols some of the time and replacing them with subtraction signs.
3. How to *not* have 0 be one of the random integers.

Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{int(random(1,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{int(random(1,10))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(\m+\n)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{int(\m*\n)}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(1,4)}
}

\newcommand{\expanded}
{
 \InitVariables
 \(x^2+{\b}x+{\c}\)
}

\newcommand{\factored}
{\((x+\m)(x+\n)\)}

\newcommand{\manysimpletrinomials}
{
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,10}
{\expanded \(=\) \factored\\}
}


\pagestyle{empty}

\title{Factoring Simple Trinomials, Generated by Random Numbers}
\author{}
\date{}




\begin{document}

\maketitle

With all positive integers, it's quite easy.

\manysimpletrinomials

I also want to incorporate negative integers to generate the following randomly. 
I'm not sure how to do it.

\(x^2-4x-12=(x-6)(x+2)\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT: And how do I avoid `\m`+`\n`=`\b`=0, generating output such as:

[image]

Comment: what bug, reference?

Comment: The bug mentioned here at the very beginning. I don't fully understand it. Sorry I don't know more details! http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320618/75762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can avoid 0 by using a random number in the range 0-9 and adding 1 (actually could just have use range 1-9:-), then some more random numbers in range 0-1 used as switches to flip signs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\InitVariables}
{
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{int(random(1,9))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{int(random(1,9))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\msign}{int(random(0,1))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\nsign}{int(random(0,1))}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{int(\ifodd\msign+\else-\fi\m\ifodd\nsign+\else-\fi\n)}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{int((\ifodd\msign+\else-\fi\m)*(\ifodd\nsign+\else-\fi\n))}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Structure}{random(1,4)}
}

\newcommand{\expanded}
{
 \InitVariables
 \(x^2{\ifnum\b>0+\fi\b}x{\ifnum\c>0+\fi\c}\)
}

\newcommand{\factored}
{\((x\ifodd\msign+\else-\fi\m)(x\ifodd\nsign+\else-\fi\n)\)}

\newcommand{\manysimpletrinomials}
{
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,...,10}
{\expanded \(=\) \factored\\}
}


\pagestyle{empty}

\title{Factoring Simple Trinomials, Generated by Random Numbers}
\author{}
\date{}




\begin{document}

\maketitle

With all positive integers, it's quite easy.

\manysimpletrinomials

I also want to incorporate negative integers to generate the following randomly. 
I'm not sure how to do it.

\(x^2-4x-12=(x-6)(x+2)\)

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks great. I'm going to try to digest it more tomorrow.

Comment: I have a question regarding `\(x^2{\ifnum\b>0+\fi\b}x{\ifnum\c>0+\fi\c}\)`. How does this command say to print a subtraction sign (and no other signs) if b<0 and/or c<0? In the `\factored` form, you had to specify which sign...`ifodd\msign+\else-\fi\m`. I'm a little confused. Is there documentation I should read? I looked through the ifthen.pdf package, but it's a little technically dense for a programming newb like me.

Comment: ifthen package is not related to this `\ifodd` is a tex primitive so see texbook (or texbytopic for a free alternative) but it's not really tex coding issue. In the first part I have used the pgfmath command which evaluates it as a number so will produce say 2 or -2 but never +2, so I could just do x+\b which would make x+2 or x+-2 which is technically correct but untidy so if it is negative I omit the + and get x-2. (@WeCanLearnAnything)