# Generating tables of random numbers

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I am trying generate tables of random numbers ( that are rounded to nearest 5 and 10).  I want to use the random number twice on each row and generate a new random number on the next row.

Table 1

```
5   5

15  15

20  20
```

Table 2

```
10 10

20 20

30 30
```

I have tried this with pgfmaths with little success.  There are two problems with my code

1) Numbers generated are not multiples of 5 or 10

2) I need n number of variables for each table.  Can I generate the numbers in the table row?

The code I have tried is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\pgfmathparse{mod(rand*60,5)}\let\var1=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{mod(rand*60,5)}\let\var2=\pgfmathresult
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
\var1 & \var1 \\  % keep var constant on row
\var2 & \var2 \\
\end{tabular}
\pgfmathparse{mod(rand*120,10)}\let\var3=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{mod(rand*120,10)}\let\var4=\pgfmathresult
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
\var3 & \var3 \\  % keep var constant on row
\var4 & \var4 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Could someone point me in the correct direction to get this to work?

Comment: numbers in the variable names

Comment: What should be the *range* of the random integers: 0-60 (in steps of 5), or something else? Please advise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the following definitions, you can define the parameters of your random numbers by

```
\setrand{<minimum>}{<maximum>}{<multiple of>}{<seed>}
```

A random number is generated by

```
\nextrand
```

which then can be accessed arbitrarily often using

```
\thisrand
```

Here is the code to be included in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\randmin{}
\newcommand\randmax{}
\newcommand\randmultof{}
\newcommand\setrand[4]%
  {\def\randmin{#1}%
   \def\randmax{#2}%
   \def\randmultof{#3}%
   \pgfmathsetseed{#4}%
  }
\newcommand\nextrand
  {\pgfmathparse{int(int((rnd*(\randmax-\randmin+1)+\randmin)/\randmultof)*\randmultof)}%
   \xdef\thisrand{\pgfmathresult}%
  }
```

This definition will generate integers uniformly distributed between *"minimum"* and *"maximum"* which then are truncated to the next multiple of *"multiple of"*. If you want to have the multiples themselves uniformly distributed, you have to choose a maximum that is smaller by one than a multiple. As an example, both of the settings

```
\setrand{0}{60}{5}{42}
\setrand{0}{64}{5}{42}
```

will generate uniformly distributed numbers between 0 and 60, the first one leading to uniform distribution before truncating to the next multiple, the second one to uniform distribution of the truncated numbers. Which of the two interpretations is the intended one isn't quite clear from the original post (at least not to me).

Here is a sample document illustrating the usage of these commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\randmin{}
\newcommand\randmax{}
\newcommand\randmultof{}
\newcommand\setrand[4]%
  {\def\randmin{#1}%
   \def\randmax{#2}%
   \def\randmultof{#3}%
   \pgfmathsetseed{#4}%
  }
\newcommand\nextrand
  {\pgfmathparse{int(int((rnd*(\randmax-\randmin+1)+\randmin)/\randmultof)*\randmultof)}%
   \xdef\thisrand{\pgfmathresult}%
  }
\begin{document}
\setrand{0}{64}{5}{42} % random numbers between 0 and 60, multiples of 5, seed 42
\begin{tabular}[t]{ r r }
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\setrand{0}{129}{10}{42} % random numbers between 0 and 120, multiples of 10, seed 42
\begin{tabular}[t]{ r r }
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand \\
\nextrand\thisrand & \thisrand
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. There's no reason for loading `tikz` though, `pgfmath` would suffice. `:)`

Comment: @GuilhermeZanotelli Thanks, changed it; just copied the OP's prefix without minimizing it ...

Comment: Note: the `random` function (pgf v3.0.1a) can't use negative numbers ! A [workaround](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/320618/14500)...

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks, I've modified the computation of the random number.

Comment: @gernot You should use `int` instead of `round` to get an equiprobable choice.

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are basically right, but I'm still not completely sure how the specification in the original post is to be understood. The code as it is now can be used to generate numbers that are uniformly distributed between the bounds (inclusively) before or after truncation to a multiple, depending on the choice of the upper bound.

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\pgfmathparse{int(random(0,12)*5)}\let\vara=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(random(0,12)*5)}\let\varb=\pgfmathresult
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
\vara & \vara \\  % keep var constant on row
\varb & \varb \\
\end{tabular}
\pgfmathparse{int(random(0,12)*10)}\let\varc=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(random(0,12)*10)}\let\vard=\pgfmathresult
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c c }
\varc & \varc \\  % keep var constant on row
\vard & \vard \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

TeX command names can not have numbers in them (with the default settings) so `\vara` not `\var1`

Comment: Thanks.  Can I calculate the variables per row in the table or do I need to calculate and assign a variable out side the table?

Comment: @StuartNorris You can do anything you want:-) If you move the `\pgfmathparse` to the first cell in each row and then use `\global\let\myvar\pgfmathresult` you can use the single variable `\myvar` everywhere just redefining it each row.

Answer (score 5):

Works only with `pdflatex` and `lualatex` (because `randint` is not yet available with `xelatex`).

The `\randomtable` command accepts

1. an optional arguments, the range *r* (default 20) meaning that multiples of 5 from 0 to 5‌*r* will be chosen (so the default is between 0 and 100);
2. a mandatory argument, the number of rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtable}{O{20}m}
 {
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { \__norris_twice:f { \fp_eval:n { randint(0,#1)*5 } } \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__norris_twice:n { #1 & #1 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__norris_twice:n { f }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomtable{2}\quad\randomtable{2}\quad\randomtable{4}

\bigskip

\randomtable[2]{2}\quad\randomtable[2]{2}\quad\randomtable[2]{4}

\end{document}
```

The second example shows that only 0, 5 and 10 can be selected.

[image]

If you want no repeated value, it's a bit more complicated (and of course slower):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\randomtable}{O{20}m}
 {
  \seq_gclear:N \g__norris_generated_seq
  \begin{tabular}{rr}
  \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { \__norris_generate:n { #1 } \\ }
  \end{tabular}
 }

\seq_new:N \g__norris_generated_seq
\tl_new:N \l__norris_random_number_tl
\cs_new:Nn \__norris_generate:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 < \seq_count:N \g__norris_generated_seq }
   {
    \__norris_twice:n { ? }
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__norris_random_number_tl { \fp_eval:n { randint(0,#1)*5 } }
    \seq_if_in:NVTF \g__norris_generated_seq \l__norris_random_number_tl
     {% redo
      \__norris_generate:n { #1 }
     }
     {
      \seq_gput_right:NV \g__norris_generated_seq \l__norris_random_number_tl
      \__norris_twice:V \l__norris_random_number_tl
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__norris_twice:n { #1 & #1 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__norris_twice:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\randomtable{2}\quad\randomtable{2}\quad\randomtable{4}

\bigskip

\randomtable[4]{2}\quad\randomtable[4]{2}\quad\randomtable[4]{5}\quad
\randomtable[4]{6}

\end{document}
```

In the last example, we have more rows than allowed by the range, so the last row has question marks.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For good measure, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

The code shown below defines a LaTeX macro called `\randtable`, which takes 1 argument: the number of rows the two-column table is supposed to have. The LaTeX macro acts as the interface to the Lua function, called `randtable`, which does the actual work.

By default, the random integers have a range of `0` to `100`, endpoints included, in steps of `5`. To change the range from `0` to `100` to `5` to `50`, change `5*(math.random(21)-1)` to `5*(math.random(10))` in the code below. (Aside: if `n` is an integer, the Lua function `math.random(n)` generates uniformly distributed integers ranging from `1` to `n`.)

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment
\begin{luacode}
function tablerand ( n )
     tex.sprint( "\\begin{tabular}[t]{cc}" ) 
     for i=1,n do
         z = 5*(math.random(21)-1)  -- random integers from 0 to 100, stepsize=5
         tex.sprint ( z .. "&" .. z .. "\\\\" )
     end
     tex.sprint( "\\end{tabular}" )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\tablerand[1]{\directlua{tablerand(#1)}} % LaTeX macro to invoke the Lua function 

\begin{document}
\tablerand{5}, \tablerand{15}, \tablerand{10}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `knitr` and R: A simple `rtable()` function make the random numbers and the table. The argument set the number of possible values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
<<echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
rtable <- function(x){
a <- sample.int(x,size=3,replace=T)*5
print(xtable(data.frame(a,a),caption="",digits=0), 
include.rownames=F, include.colnames=F, 
caption.placement = "top",booktabs = T)}
@

<<results="asis",echo=F>>=
set.seed(123)
rtable(3)
rtable(30)
rtable(3000)
@
\end{document}
```

> [image: rtable]