# Random integers with differing probabilities

Tags: pgfmath, random-numbers

This is a follow-up to [my last post on random numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338717/pick-randomly-between-1-or-1).

My new question is:

Say I want `\n` to generated (kind of) randomly, such that

`\n`=1  10% of the time

`\n`=2  20% of the time

`\n`=3  30% of the time

`\n`=4  40% of the time

This code makes each possible value of `\n` equally likely. How do I weight the probabilities as listed above?

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{1}{2}{3}{4}}
\foreach\x in {1,...,50}
{\pgfmathrandomitem{\n}{choices}\n\\}

\end{document}
```

Comment: For your example, I would guess using `{{1}{2}{2}{3}{3}{3}{4}{4}{4}{4}}` as your random list should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a variation of my answer to your previous question, and nest three `ifthenelse`s.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {1,...,2000} {
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{rnd}
 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.1,1,ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.3,2,ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.6,3,4)))}\pgfmathresult
}
\end{document}
```

Borrowing a bit from egreg's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{1}\newcounter{2}\newcounter{3}\newcounter{4}
\foreach\x in {1,...,2000} {
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmp}{rnd}
 \pgfmathparse{ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.1,1,ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.3,2,ifthenelse(\tmp<=0.6,3,4)))}\pgfmathresult
 \stepcounter{\pgfmathresult}
}

1: \the\value{1}\par
2: \the\value{2}\par
3: \the\value{3}\par
4: \the\value{4}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\myrandom}{%
  \expandafter\domyrandom\pdfuniformdeviate 10 \domyrandom
}
\def\domyrandom#1\domyrandom{%
  \ifcase#1
  1\or
  2\or
  2\or
  3\or
  3\or
  3\or
  4\or
  4\or
  4\or
  4\fi
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {1,...,100}{\myrandom\space}

\newcounter{1}\newcounter{2}\newcounter{3}\newcounter{4}
\foreach \x in {1,...,1000}{\stepcounter{\myrandom}}
1: \the\value{1}\par
2: \the\value{2}\par
3: \the\value{3}\par
4: \the\value{4}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Soon to be available in `expl3` ;)

Answer (score 5):

While I'm sure there's a direct method to generate integers from 1 to 4 so that they have probabilities 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, and 0.4, an *indirect* or two-step method is more straightforward to set up. First, generate an integer between 1 and 10 randomly. (I.e., each integer has `P=0.1`.) Second, check if the integer is less than 2, 4, and 7, respectively, and assign the numbers "1", "2", "3" accordingly -- and associate the number "4" with the "none of the above" category, i.e. if the integer is between 7 and 10.

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based implementation of this idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\x{%
  \directlua{x=math.random(10) % draw an integer between 1 and 10
             if       x<2 then tex.sprint(1) % true if x==1
               elseif x<4 then tex.sprint(2) % true if x==2 or 3
               elseif x<7 then tex.sprint(3) % true if x==4, 5, or 6
               else            tex.sprint(4) % true if x==7, 8, 9, or 10
             end}}
\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this example
\x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x
\x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x
\x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x
\x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x; \x, \x, \x, \x, \x
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling

create an function  that has x values from 0 to 1, with y values that output the integer values you want, in the distribution you want.  Then use a random number generator to produce a number between 0 and 1, and then lookup the value of your function.  your function can be an 100 element array, in which the "x" value is multiplied by 100 and rounded down...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your posting currently reads more like a general statement about generating (pseudo-)random numbers than a LaTeX-based solution to the OP's query. Please consider editing your posting to explain how you would implement your recommendations in a LaTeX document.